# What is the best practice for model fetching from external source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have the ActiveRecord model like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

And I have Api class that fetches the attributes from web for `User` and returns a hash, which in turn needs some preprocessing to fit into the user model. E.g. the response from api is `{response: {id:20, stars:{count:20}}}` needs to be processed to `user.id=20` and `user.stars_count=20`.

Now there are 2 ways that I can easily see to do the fecting thing. One way is add a method to Api like get_user, that does all the processing returns a new `User` model with filled attributes. The other is to add `fetch` method to User that does all the processing.

In the first case I don't like that my Api class will be filled with a lot of `get_model` methods like `get_user`, `get_post`, `get_all_posts_for_user` etc. and quickly can become unmanagable. In the second case the model is filled with a lot of preprocessing stuff methods like `fetch`, `fetch_all_posts` and looks nasty too.

So what is the best practice to deal with this problem?

Comment: if you got `{response: {id:20, stars:{count:20}}}` data inside your controller, you can easily get these data as `params` (e.g. `params[:response][:id]`)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Active Resource](https://github.com/rails/activeresource), you don't have to do what you are doing manually.